# $N=2^7\cdot3^5\cdot5^6\cdot7^8$. How many factors of $N$ are divisible by $50$ and not by $500$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

My attempt:

$50=5^2 \cdot 2$

$500=5^3 \cdot 2^2$

Factors divisible by $50=5 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 9=1890$

Factors divisible by $500=4 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 9=1296$

So, the answer is $=1890-1296=594$

But the question is what if I want to do it directly? Without using complements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
N = 50\cdot2^6\cdot3^5\cdot5^4\cdot7^8
$$
to avoid divisibility by 500, we may take no 5's with 1 to 6 2's, or no 2's with 1 to 4 5's or no 2's or 5's at all, i.e. 11 cases. the 3's and 7's are not restricted, so give $6 \times 9=54$ cases.

$$
11 \times 54 = 594
$$

Comment: @Jihad thx for the edit - will use \cdot in future!

Comment: btw did you see my late contribution to your question re pairs of relatively prime factors of 360?

Answer (score 2):

You might divide by $50$ and then count the factors of the resulting number that are not divisible by $10$. To do this directly, you might add those which are not divisible by $2$ with those that are not divisible by $5$.

But this problem probably *is* best handled by inclusion-exclusion.